# Angularjs search/filter in nested ng-repeats?

Tags: angularjs

I'm stuck with the filtering of AngularJS. The easy things do work, like search on Names, but what I can't figure out is how to search in nested ng-repeats.

The output is clear and correct, the only thing I can't figure out is how to search for a specific Sheep in all the farms.

```
<fieldset>
    <input type="text" placeholder="search farm" ng-model="search.$">
</fieldset>

<section ng-repeat="farm in farms | filter: search | filter:search.sheep">
    <h4>Farm: {{ farm.name }}</h4>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="sheep in farm.sheeps">
            {{ sheep }}
        </li>
    </ul>

</section>

<aside>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="sheep in sheeps">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="search.sheep" value="{{ sheep.name }}">
                {{ sheep.name }}
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</aside>
```

The JSON structure of Farm:

```
{
    id: 3,
    name: "Farmname",
    sheeps: [
        "Sheep 1",
        "Sheep 2",
        "Sheep 3",
        "Sheep 4"
    ],
}
```

Or is it easier, if I make the JSON like this?

```
 {
            id: 3,
            name: "Farmname",
            sheeps: "Sheep 1 - Sheep 2 - Sheep 3"
}
```

Use-case: Click on Sheepname > show Farm that has Sheep in his Farm.

Comment: would need a custom filter to transpose name to ID if that is what you are asking

Comment: @chartlietfl changed it a little, it's also oke now to search by name - because Sheep has unique names.

Comment: Added more possibilities for the json, to make it easier maybe.

Comment: need to loop through farms data and find which one has the sheep you want